# Add method to jQuery .validate to check if summernote textarea is empty

Tags: jquery, html, validation, summernote

I am trying to add a method to the jQuery .validate to check if a Summernote (WYSIWYG editor) textarea is empty and I can not get the method to trigger (the alert I placed in it doe not show). There is no error in the console.

The method is:

```
//Add validation method to check for an empty Award Description
$.validator.addMethod("htmlEditorEmpty", function(value, element) {
    alert("checking");
    return this.optional(element) || value.summernote('isEmpty');
}, "Please enter details");
```

This is called by (other validations before and after this work):

```
awardDescription: {
    htmlEditorEmpty: true,
    maxlength: 1500,
},
```

Checks the HTML:

```
<div class="col-lg-3 col-md-3 col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div>
            <textarea class="summernote" id="awardDescription" name="awardDescription" rows="3"></textarea>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have placed this in the submitHandler:

```
if ($('#awardDescription').summernote('isEmpty')) {//using id
    alert('contents is empty1');
}

if ($('awardDescription').summernote('isEmpty')) {//using name
    alert('contents is empty2');
}
```

The first works (i.e., displays when empty only) while the second always displays (i.e., even when a value is entered). I include this information because I believe that .validate use the name rather than the id. I may be wrong.

Answer (score 5):

Summernote has a built in test for this.  Here's the code I'm using:

```
if ($('#summernote').summernote('isEmpty'))
{
  alert('editor content is empty');
}
```

Which is what you are using and why your alert fires.  Your other test isn't testing a valid id or name with the syntax you are using.  I'd think the browser would throw an error or ignore your second test

To test using the name, use val()
 $('form[name="???"] input[name="???"]').val(),

Comment: I find that this always returns false, no matter what

Answer (score 0):

If you are using [jQuery Validation](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) that time you can use `addMethod` to validate summernote textarea.

```
$("#form-id").validate({
    ignore: [],
    description: { summerNoteRequired: true },

    errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
        if(element.attr('name') == 'description') {
           $(error).insertBefore($('#description-error'));
       // you can create your own element to show error or using parent element you can manage error message
        }
    }
});

$.validator.addMethod('summerNoteRequired', function (value, element) {
    return !$('#description').summernote('isEmpty');
}, 'Description field is required');
```

Note: You can use: highlight, unhighlight and `errorPlacement` as per your requirement.